# Open/Load view from another project of same solution in WPF

Tags: wpf, view

In my application, in a single solution, there are two different project.
Lets say, Project A and Project B.

From the view of first project A, on button click event, I want to load the view from the second project B.

Could you please guide me.

Thanks.
Ruhul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a reference to Project B from Project A in Visual Studio: `Project->Add Reference->Projects->Solution`.

Then you can create an instance of the view class that is defined in Project B and use it as appropriate:

```
private void btnClick_In_Project_A(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //if viewB is a window:
    ProjectB.ViewB viewB = new ProjectB.ViewB();
    viewB.Show();

    //or if viewB is a UserControl:
    Window win = new Window();
    win.Content = new ProjectB.ViewB();
    win.Show();
}
```

Project B should be a `WPF User Control Library` or a `WPF User Control Library`.

Comment: It Works. Thanks a lot mm8.